# Print "beep boop bop" using complicated methods

Tags: code-golf, kolmogorov-complexity

This challenge is pretty simple: you need to alert / print / show to the user the text "beep boop bop" (or "beep\nboop\nbop", with newlines), but it needs to be obfuscated. (where you couldn't see anything saying "beep", "boop", or "bop"). Points are calculated where your point value is in **characters** (**not** bytes)

Comment: i don't see the pointvin overriding the community consensus on scoring solutions based on bytes rather than characters. Also note that [tag:obfuscation] is not an objective criterion, however, if you specifically mean that the strings `beep`, `boop` and `bop` cannot appear in the source, then that is fine (though a little boring)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bash, 16 bytes

```
echo b{ee,oo,o}p
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 21 bytes

```perl6
put <bee boo bo>X~'p'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7/7@gtETBJik1VSEpPx@I7SLq1AvU//8HAA)

Prints all the words on one line by joining all the prefixes with the last letter `p`